# How to arrange image dynamically

Tags: ios, swift3

I got images from an array which include square and rectangle image. Then I determine the image size for the arrangement. The images from array are randomly in rectangle or square size. The current result I had is below one

[image]

I couldn't arrange both square images as like this the actual result I wanted the below one

[image]

```
func retreiveImgFromMemory() {
    //get from memory
    let imgArr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "adsImgArr")

    //Rec Image
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = 414
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = 235
    var yPosition:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat = 0

    //Sqr Image
    let sqrImgWidth:CGFloat = 203
    let sqrImgHeight:CGFloat = 235.33

    for img in imgArr! {
        let imgURL = URL(string: img as! String)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imgURL!)
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
        let imageSize = Int(image.size.width)

        //1242
        if imageSize > 600 {
            let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

            imageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
            imageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
            imageView.frame.origin.x = 0
            imageView.center = self.view.center
            imageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let spacer:CGFloat = 0

            yPosition+=200 + spacer
        }
        //600
        else{
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

            imageView.frame.size.width = sqrImgWidth
            imageView.frame.size.height = sqrImgHeight
            imageView.frame.origin.x = 0
            imageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let spacer:CGFloat = 10

            yPosition+=200 + spacer
            scrollViewContentSize+=imageHeight + spacer
        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: scrollViewContentSize)
    stopLoadingSpinner()
}
```

Comment: you can use stakcview to achieve this design

Comment: Add these images in UICollectionView and play with device size in terms of ratio

Comment: @PankajBhardwaj Got any swift 3 code example?

Comment: @Vinodh May I know how to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

To achive this you have to initially download images asynchronously. after downloading images you have to calculate their size. and populate images in UICollectionView with waterfalllayout

To download image asynchrnously use this [library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). and to get image data use below code

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
    print(image)
})
```

and to implement waterfall layout in UICollectionView.
use below extension

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
fileprivate func < <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (l?, r?):
        return l < r
    case (nil, _?):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

fileprivate func > <T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (l?, r?):
        return l > r
    default:
        return rhs < lhs
    }
}


@objc public protocol CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                         sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize

    @objc optional func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat

    @objc optional func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat

    @objc optional func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets

    @objc optional func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat

    @objc optional func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                                        columnCountForSection section: Int) -> Int
}

public enum CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirection: Int {
    case chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionShortestFirst
    case chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionLeftToRight
    case chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionRightToLeft
}

public  let CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader = "CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader"
public  let CHTCollectionElementKindSectionFooter = "CHTCollectionElementKindSectionFooter"
public class CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    public var columnCount: Int {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}

    public var minimumColumnSpacing: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}

    public var minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}

    public var headerHeight: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}

    public var footerHeight: CGFloat {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}

    public var sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }}


    public var itemRenderDirection: CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirection {
        didSet {
            invalidateLayout()
        }
    }


    //    private property and method above.
    public weak var delegate: CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout? {
        get {
            return self.collectionView!.delegate as? CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout
        }
    }
    public var columnHeights: [[CGFloat]]
    public var sectionItemAttributes: [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]
    public var allItemAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    public var headersAttributes: [Int: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    public var footersAttributes: [Int: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    public var unionRects: [NSValue]
    public let unionSize = 20

    override public init() {
        self.headerHeight = 0.0
        self.footerHeight = 0.0
        self.columnCount = 2
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        self.minimumColumnSpacing = 10
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.itemRenderDirection =
            CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirection.chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionShortestFirst

        headersAttributes = [:]
        footersAttributes = [:]
        unionRects = []
        columnHeights = []
        allItemAttributes = []
        sectionItemAttributes = []

        super.init()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func columnCountForSection (_ section: Int) -> Int {
        if let columnCount = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, columnCountForSection: section) {
            return columnCount
        } else {
            return self.columnCount
        }
    }

    public func itemWidthInSectionAtIndex (_ section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        var insets: UIEdgeInsets
        if let sectionInsets = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, insetForSectionAtIndex: section) {
            insets = sectionInsets
        } else {
            insets = self.sectionInset
        }
        let width: CGFloat = self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width - insets.left - insets.right
        let columnCount = self.columnCountForSection(section)
        let spaceColumCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(columnCount - 1)
        return floor((width - (spaceColumCount * self.minimumColumnSpacing)) / CGFloat(columnCount))
    }

    override public func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        let numberOfSections = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
        if numberOfSections == 0 {
            return
        }

        self.headersAttributes = [:]
        self.footersAttributes = [:]
        self.unionRects = []
        self.columnHeights = []
        self.allItemAttributes = []
        self.sectionItemAttributes = []

        for section in 0 ..< numberOfSections {
            let columnCount = self.columnCountForSection(section)
            var sectionColumnHeights: [CGFloat] = []
            for idx in 0 ..< columnCount {
                sectionColumnHeights.append(CGFloat(idx))
            }
            self.columnHeights.append(sectionColumnHeights)
        }

        var top: CGFloat = 0.0
        var attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()

        for section in 0 ..< numberOfSections {
            /*
             * 1. Get section-specific metrics (minimumInteritemSpacing, sectionInset)
             */
            var minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat
            if let miniumSpaceing = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex: section) {
                minimumInteritemSpacing = miniumSpaceing
            } else {
                minimumInteritemSpacing = self.minimumColumnSpacing
            }

            var sectionInsets: UIEdgeInsets
            if let insets = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, insetForSectionAtIndex: section) {
                sectionInsets = insets
            } else {
                sectionInsets = self.sectionInset
            }

            let width = self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width - sectionInsets.left - sectionInsets.right
            let columnCount = self.columnCountForSection(section)
            let spaceColumCount = CGFloat(columnCount - 1)
            let itemWidth = floor((width - (spaceColumCount * self.minimumColumnSpacing)) / CGFloat(columnCount))

            /*
             * 2. Section header
             */
            var heightHeader: CGFloat
            if let height = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, heightForHeaderInSection: section) {
                heightHeader = height
            } else {
                heightHeader = self.headerHeight
            }

            if heightHeader > 0 {
                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader, with: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section))
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: top, width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: heightHeader)
                self.headersAttributes[section] = attributes
                self.allItemAttributes.append(attributes)

                top = attributes.frame.maxY
            }
            top += sectionInsets.top
            for idx in 0 ..< columnCount {
                self.columnHeights[section][idx]=top
            }

            /*
             * 3. Section items
             */
            let itemCount = self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            var itemAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

            // Item will be put into shortest column.
            for idx in 0 ..< itemCount {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: idx, section: section)

                let columnIndex = self.nextColumnIndexForItem(idx, section: section)
                let xOffset = sectionInsets.left + (itemWidth + self.minimumColumnSpacing) * CGFloat(columnIndex)

                let yOffset = ((self.columnHeights[section] as AnyObject).object (at: columnIndex) as AnyObject).doubleValue
                let itemSize = self.delegate?.collectionView(self.collectionView!, layout: self, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
                var itemHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
                if itemSize?.height > 0 && itemSize?.width > 0 {
                    itemHeight = floor(itemSize!.height * itemWidth / itemSize!.width)
                }

                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(yOffset!), width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
                itemAttributes.append(attributes)
                self.allItemAttributes.append(attributes)

                self.columnHeights[section][columnIndex] = attributes.frame.maxY + minimumInteritemSpacing

            }
            self.sectionItemAttributes.append(itemAttributes)

            /*
             * 4. Section footer
             */
            var footerHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
            let columnIndex  = self.longestColumnIndexInSection(section)
            top = self.columnHeights[section][columnIndex] - minimumInteritemSpacing + sectionInsets.bottom

            if let height = self.delegate?.collectionView?(self.collectionView!, layout: self, heightForFooterInSection: section) {
                footerHeight = height
            } else {
                footerHeight = self.footerHeight
            }

            if footerHeight > 0 {
                attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CHTCollectionElementKindSectionFooter, with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
                attributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: top, width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: footerHeight)
                self.footersAttributes[section] = attributes
                self.allItemAttributes.append(attributes)
                top = attributes.frame.maxY
            }

            for idx in 0 ..< columnCount {
                self.columnHeights[section][idx] = top
            }
        }

        var idx = 0
        let itemCounts = self.allItemAttributes.count
        while idx < itemCounts {
            let rect1 = self.allItemAttributes[idx].frame
            idx = min(idx + unionSize, itemCounts) - 1
            let rect2 = self.allItemAttributes[idx].frame
            self.unionRects.append(NSValue(cgRect:rect1.union(rect2)))
            idx += 1
        }
    }

    override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        let numberOfSections = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
        if numberOfSections == 0 {
            return CGSize.zero
        }

        var contentSize = self.collectionView!.bounds.size as CGSize

        if columnHeights.count > 0 {
            if let height = self.columnHeights[columnHeights.count - 1].first {
                contentSize.height = height
                return contentSize
            }
        }
        return CGSize.zero
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section >= self.sectionItemAttributes.count {
            return nil
        }
        let list = self.sectionItemAttributes[indexPath.section]
        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item >= list.count {
            return nil
        }
        return list[indexPath.item]
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        var attribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
        if elementKind == CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            attribute = self.headersAttributes[indexPath.section]
        } else if elementKind == CHTCollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
            attribute = self.footersAttributes[indexPath.section]
        }
        guard let returnAttribute = attribute else {
            return UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
        }
        return returnAttribute
    }

    override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var begin = 0, end = self.unionRects.count
        var attrs: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

        for i in 0 ..< end {
            let unionRect = self.unionRects[i]
            if rect.intersects(unionRect.cgRectValue) {
                begin = i * unionSize
                break
            }
        }
        for i in (0 ..< self.unionRects.count).reversed() {
            let unionRect = self.unionRects[i]
            if rect.intersects(unionRect.cgRectValue) {
                end = min((i + 1) * unionSize, self.allItemAttributes.count)
                break
            }
        }
        for i in begin ..< end {
            let attr = self.allItemAttributes[i]
            if rect.intersects(attr.frame) {
                attrs.append(attr)
            }
        }

        return attrs
    }

    override public func shouldInvalidateLayout (forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let oldBounds = self.collectionView!.bounds
        if newBounds.width != oldBounds.width {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }


    /**
     *  Find the shortest column.
     *
     *  @return index for the shortest column
     */
    public func shortestColumnIndexInSection (_ section: Int) -> Int {
        var index = 0
        var shorestHeight = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        for (idx, height) in self.columnHeights[section].enumerated() {
            if height < shorestHeight {
                shorestHeight = height
                index = idx
            }
        }
        return index
    }

    /**
     *  Find the longest column.
     *
     *  @return index for the longest column
     */

    public func longestColumnIndexInSection (_ section: Int) -> Int {
        var index = 0
        var longestHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

        for (idx, height) in self.columnHeights[section].enumerated() {
            if height > longestHeight {
                longestHeight = height
                index = idx
            }
        }
        return index

    }

    /**
     *  Find the index for the next column.
     *
     *  @return index for the next column
     */
    public func nextColumnIndexForItem (_ item: Int, section: Int) -> Int {
        var index = 0
        let columnCount = self.columnCountForSection(section)
        switch self.itemRenderDirection {
        case .chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionShortestFirst :
            index = self.shortestColumnIndexInSection(section)
        case .chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionLeftToRight :
            index = (item%columnCount)
        case .chtCollectionViewWaterfallLayoutItemRenderDirectionRightToLeft:
            index = (columnCount - 1) - (item % columnCount)
        }
        return index
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for you answer, do you have in swift 3 code?

Comment: you mean you need swift3 version of Waterfall Layout extension @NSX

Comment: Yes Ganesh, do you have it?

Comment: This will support Swift 3 also not much difference @NSX